# Xamarin.Forms: Localization of the UWP app

Tags: xamarin, localization, uwp, xamarin.forms

If I run my app on an UWP device I get the following warning in the `Output` window:

> MakePRI : warning 0xdef00522: Resources found for language(s) 'en,de' but no resources found for default language(s): 'de-DE,en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899

Don't know if this is related, but I also get

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2459,5): warning : APPX4001: Build property AppxBundlePlatforms is not explicitly set and is calculated based on currently building architecture. Use 'Create App Package' wizard or edit project file to set it.

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Apps/jj552947.aspx#makepriexe_warnings_and_error_messages) states, that I have language specific resources, which I haven't qualified with the language tag. How can I find out, which resources these are?

I have images in the `Assets` folder, but they are language independent ones.  Furthermore, I've set the default language in the `Package.appxmanifest` to `de-DE`. If I search for the language abbrevation from the warning, I can only find a `priconfig.xml` and `AppxManifest.xml`, both in the `Debug` output folder.

What should I do to remove this warning?

**Edit:**

The warning seems to disappear if I add a `AppResources.en-US.resx` file (currently I have `en-US` set as default language in `Package.appxmanifest`). Additionally, I have a file for `AppResources.de.resx` and `AppResources.resx` (should be `en`). But why does the [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UsingResxLocalization/UWP) doesn't need such a file, despite there should be the same settings? What I'm missing?

Comment: This message is related to strings. Do you have any Resources.resw files? They are usually under Strings folder in UWP project, f.e. Strings->en-us->Resources.resw. I suspect you have folders named "en" and "de" in there, try to rename them to "en-us" and "de-de".

Comment: I have `resw` files, but only in the debug build artefacts. There is currently no *Strings* folder in the UWP project.

Comment: This might be the problem. I'm not 100% sure how localization works in xamarin.forms, but in pure UWP project you'll need to have Strings folder with language-specific sub-folders if you declared supported languages. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources).

Comment: [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) is the description for XF, but only WP8 is mentioned. I don't know if I have to do the same steps for UWP. The localization approach uses `resx` files, so I don't need the extra strings (perhaps only if I'm doing something natively) I think.

Comment: You can check those code samples, they have UWP projects too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that in more detail. Currently, I can see that the images are localized (Assets > Images) in one of the sample projects. What should I do if I don't have localized images? Can I have them in the *Assets* folder? There is no *Strings* folder in the sample projects. I'll have to download the projects to see if I get the same warning on compiling.

Comment: Images should only be localized if you need them localized. Otherwise you just don't put them in language specific folders, so yes, you can have them all in Assets. And it seems like if you use xamarin.forms way of localizing, you won't need Strings in the UWP project indeed.

Comment: Two questions: 1) How can I see the build output in a file? The ouput window is clearled too fast. 2) How many characters should have the default language in `Package.appxmanifest`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153799/discussion-between-andrey-ashikhmin-and-testing).

Answer (score 6):

> The warning seems to disappear if I add a AppResources.en-US.resx file (currently I have en-US set as default language in Package.appxmanifest). Additionally, I have a file for AppResources.de.resx and AppResources.resx (should be en). But why does the sample project doesn't need such a file, despite there should be the same settings? What I'm missing?

As you said, the `AppResources.resx` is en. And you could expand the Properties node in the Portable Class Library (PCL) project and double-click on the AssemblyInfo.cs file. Add the following line to the file to set the neutral resources assembly language to English:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

This informs the resource manager of the app's default culture, therefore ensuring that the strings defined in the language neutral RESX file (AppResources.resx) will be displayed when the app is running in one the English locales.

You have set `en-US` as default language in `Package.appxmanifest`, However, there is no such file corresponding to it. So it will throw warning.

The default language of the sample project is `en-US`, and there is no such file corresponding to it. It also throw the same warning in my side. if you modify the default language to `en`, the warning disappear. Because it has set `AppResources.resx` as `en` in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Foe more you could refer to [`AssemblyInfo`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/#AssemblyInfo.cs), [Supported languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/supported-languages).

Comment: So if I get this right the default language in `Package.appxmanifest` doesn't need a 4 character string. If I set it to `en` and also define the neutral resources assembly language to `en` I should be fine? Does it matter which language is the default language?

Comment: Yes,it doesn't need a 4 character string and It does not matter which language is the default language. However, the  language set in this three section need to be identical.

Comment: Which three sections do you mean? `Package.appxmanifest`, `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the PCL and ...? If I set the language to `en` in the sample *UsingResxLocalization* I still get *Resources found for language(s) 'en,de,de-ch,es,fr,id,ja,ms,pt,pt-br,zh-hans,zh-hant' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'.* Now I tried it in my project and on a real device with the same result. The warning doesn't disappear. Should I add `NeutralResourcesLanguage` also to the `AssemblyInfo.cs`of the UWP project? This also doesn't seem to change it. I'm using VS2015 with Xamarin 4.6.0.299 installed.

Comment: Three sections are `Package.appxmanifest`, `AssemblyInfo.cs` ,`AppResources.resx`.  To test this, you should rebuild your `pcl` library at first. And try to run your project in release model.

Comment: Ok in release mode the warning is gone, but not in debug mode. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

Just to extend answer from Nico Zhu - MSFT
if you are using .Net Standard there is no assemblyInfo.cs file because everything is stored in the csproj file. So just go to properties of the shared project and change the Project neutral language to whatever your resx default file is.
or you can right click on the project and edit the project and the line below.

For me problem was,after converting from PCL to Net Standard, suddently UWP application wasnt picking the default resource file which was en-US. I recognized because i was having this setting in assmeblyInfo.cs and since It was removed, it didnt work. But somehow it works fine for Android project.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[image]