# How to set UWP language on runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

i'm currently developing a cross-platform App using Xamarin.Forms 3.4 and Visual Studio 2017 (latest version by now).

Since that App should support multiple languages which can be changed on runtime, i'm currently looking into ways to get this done. I already added several resources and translated all interface elements which works just fine. I read through this article to get started:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/

For now, when using the UWP app, the language is automatically set to my current system settings, which is the german language, even if the default app language is english. Thats fine.

Now, I got a method which configures my current language by setting several information, like the default CultureInfo object. That method looks like follows:

```
    public void UpdateAppLanguage()
    {
      CultureInfo ci;
      Language l;

      // storage is a class containing several persistent information, like
      // the language selected by the user to be used
      // the Local attribute states if the language is actually present on
      // the current user's system
      if(Storage.GetCurrentLanguage().Local == true)
      {
        // language is present locally, so the user wants to use that one for
        // the interface
        ci = new CultureInfo(Storage.GetCurrentLanguage().Code);
        AppResources.Culture = ci;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = ci;
        DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().SetLocale(ci); // set the Thread for locale-aware methods
      }
      else
      {
        // no preferences available yet, use the system's current ci
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.UWP)
          ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        else
          ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

        l = new Language{
          Name = ci.EnglishName,
          Code = ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
        };

        Storage.SetCurrentLanguage(l);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        AppResources.Culture = ci; // set the RESX for resource localization
        DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().SetLocale(ci); // set the Thread for locale-aware methods
     }
    }
```

I'm currently testing with a language set, and that language is English.

And here is the dependency service implementation for the UWP sub-project:

```
  public class Localize : stereopoly.ILocalize
  {
    public void SetLocale (CultureInfo ci)
    {
      //Windows.Globalization.ApplicationSettings.PrimaryLanguageOverride = ci.Name;
      Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "EN-US";
      Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
      Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
    }

    public CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo ()
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I also tried to set the language to EN-US by force, which doesn't work either. I'm calling the UpdateAppLanguage() method even before the initial Application.InitializeComponent() method runs, I also tried calling it within the OnStart() event method, neither works.

I'd expect the language change getting applied since its executed even before the actual Application starts, but I can switch the several pages of my app as often as I want, the language will always be german, no matter what I do.
I found several answers to this question for plain UWP apps, but not for Xamarin.Forms implementations of UWP projects and that seems to be the problem here, because no other hint regarding pure UWP apps seem to work.

Do you have any idea what might help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This might seem stupid, but usually the syntax is "en-US"

Comment: Tried that one as well too before changing it to en-US, same result. Thanks anyway :).

Comment: And you are not getting any exception whatsoever? Have you confirmed the methods are being called?

Comment: Yeah, both. Added alot of System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() in there, the if-branch within UpdateAppLanguage() gets called, as well as the dependency service. No exception, no complains, no build warnings whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem, it was just as simple as it usually is when it comes to such errors.
It turns out that all bootstrap projects like the UWP, iOS and Android sub-projects also inherit the Assembly Neutral Language from the parent project, no matter what configuration is defined in the specific sub-project (at least thats how it works for UWP). I just noticed that I can set an Assembly Neutral Language within the settings of my .Net main project, and as soon as I did that, all the warnings disappeared and my UWP app ended up showing english text instead of the system default german one. I can also switch back to german now, even though I still have to restart the app to get all frames translated, but thats not that big of a problem, I can work on fixing that up later on. Here's the link that finally got me covered:
[Xamarin.Forms: Localization of the UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072032/xamarin-forms-localization-of-the-uwp-app?rq=1)

Thanks for your amazing help anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are targeting at least UWP 16299 (FCU), because before that version UWP had issues properly switching languages in debug mode. If you run in Release mode however, it should work normally.

In addition the UWP app needs to know it supports a given language, because this is generated at compile time (using `<Resource Language="x-generate"/>` in `Package.appxmanifest`)

You can do this by adding a `Strings` folder in your UWP project and then adding multiple subfolders - one for each supported language. Finally in each of them add a `Resources.resw` file (right-click folder, Add > New item..., Resources file (RESW)). The result will look like this.

[image: RESW folders]

Then inside each RESW file add some resource. I usually put in `AppName`, as I often localize it as well:

[image: Resource]

After this, the app should pick up on the fact that you support the given language and display localized.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work as well. See the link above, thats how I localized my project, the main project contains all the resources as .resx files, but not the UWP project iself, that one will inherit the resources from the global project. But I can give you the details of the AppxManifest.xml file, which contains all resource-related information it found. The Package.appxmanifest contains exactly the line you mentioned, and the generated AppxManifest.xml looks like follows in the resources part:

Comment: <Resources>
    <Resource Language="EN-US" />
    <Resource Language="DE" />
  </Resources>
As you can see, all the languages are found and properly known to the UWP program i'm currently running in Debug mode. I don't know how to specify the UWP version you mentioned though, my project properties show a target version of Windows 10 1803 ((build 17134). Is that what you ment?

Comment: @user3246033    You have to check the *minimum version*, that has to be Fall Creator Update (build 16299) or higher

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and the minimum version is exactly that build number, so there shouldn't be any problem with that I guess.

Comment: If you try release mode, does it help?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to help, but I encountered this message when compiling the release build, will have to figure out how to fix that and if thats the actual reason: 2>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : warning PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found for language(s) 'de' but no resources found for default language(s): ''. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899

Comment: After googling this issue, I found out that i'd have to set the default language in two locations, within the project file and within the AssemblyInfo.cs file. I did both things and set it to "en-US", but when building the project, it still shows me the warning above. I don't find any other solution on the web. I can probably open up the entire project repository for someone more experienced to take a look onto this, since I get the feeling that there is deffinitely something going wrong here.

Comment: Yes, if you provide a public repo, I will gladly try it out on my side

Comment: Thanks, I just put it onto GitHub, since its yet on a local GitLab. I planned to transfer it to GitHub sooner or later anyway. Here is the link: https://github.com/Timtam/stereopoly-app

Comment: I didn't try how the app reacts under environments with other languages set as system language yet though. The issue occurs to me because my system language is not set to english, it might be required to change the system language as well to reproduce this issue. At least the build problem should be fixable without doing so anyway I hope.